# Scala illegal method name?

Tags: scala

Strange error:

```
scala> Parameter.with("published", false)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'with' found.
       Parameter.with("published", false)
                 ^
```

Scala, this object is from Java RestFB library, [this is the `Parameter` object's javadoc](http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/Parameter.html).
Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`with` is a reserved keyword in Scala.

You need to wrap the method name in back-ticks to specify that you're not using the built-in keyword:

```
Parameter.`with`("published", false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try backticks around the `with`:

```
Parameter.`with`("published, false")
```

`with` is a Scala keyword. It is used to mix in traits.